# VSTS import Key Vault Certificate to a file on HostedVS build

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

How can I import certificates from Key Vault to a folder on HostedVS17?

Currently, I have a key Vault task that accesses all the certificates. How can I import them to a temp folder for subsequent task scripts to execute? I am using HostedVS2017

Answer (score 0):

can add two tasks to import certificates from Key Vault into files. Detail steps as below:

1. Add an **Azure Key Vault task** to specify the key vault you want to download
2. Add a **PowerShell task** to import certificates into files

   Assume there has a certificate with the name `cer1` in your key vault, then you can use the powershell script `echo $(cer1) > myfile` to import it into the file `myfile`.

Besides, you can use the certificates **as variables** directly. As above example, you can use the variable `$(cer1)` directly.